# Why does GetAttr not work on cloudformation template parameters?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Have a collection of cloudformation templates in a parent-child relationship and want to pass an AWS::IAM::Role into the parameters of a child stack and use GetAttr to get the Arn.

This fails validation because can only call GetAttr on resources, not on parameters.

Anyone know/guess why this is designed in this way?

It's not a problem as it can be worked around by just passing the Arn into the stack, I'm just curious really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `Fn::GetAttr` and `Parameters` are trying to do in *AWS CloudFormation* is fundamentally different. As per AWS docs:

> The intrinsic function Fn::GetAtt returns the value of an attribute
>   from a resource in the template.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

> You can use the optional Parameters section to pass values into your
>   template when you create a stack. With parameters, you can create
>   templates that are customized each time you create a stack.

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

I believe your confusion is stemming from the fact that you're trying to think of this in terms of the object-oriented/some other programming paradigm, where `Resources` and `Parameters` are some kind of objects and `Fn::GetAttr` is a generic function which retrieves the value of a reference that's passed in as an argument.

Comment: I don't believe this is what @chestercodes asked. He is asking why the argument to `Fn::GetAtt` has to be a string and cannot be a parameter value. From the `Fn::GetAtt` documentation:


"For the Fn::GetAtt logical resource name, you cannot use functions. You must specify a string that is a resource's logical ID."


I wonder about this also. You cannot get the attribute of a resource determined at run-time. You need to provide the string value of the resource when you run the template.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to access the resource attributes like ARN and Name in the nested stack. If I pass resource string and use GetAtt to get these, I dont need to pass them as two parameters. With this limitation, I had to pass them as two parameters.