# Get Availability Zone from Subnet Parameter in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have

```
Parameters
  Zookeeper1SubnetParam:
    Description: Subnet where Zookeeper 1 should run
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  Zookeeper1AZ:
    Description: Availability Zone of the Subnet
    Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name
```

From this I'm creating an [ENI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-network-interface.html) (which requires a subnet) and an [EBS Volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) (which requires an availability zone).

Here's the ENI:

```
Zookeeper1IPResource:
    Properties:
      Description: Zookeeper1-IP
      GroupSet:
        - Fn::GetAtt:
            - ZookeeperSecurityGroup
            - GroupId
      PrivateIpAddress:
        Ref: Zookeeper1IPParam
      SubnetId:
        Ref: Zookeeper1SubnetParam
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
```

And here's the EBS:

```
Zookeeper1EBSVolume:
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Ref: Zookeeper1AZ
      Size: 8
      VolumeType: gp2
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
```

I find it really bad for user experience, to also ask as a parameter for an availability zone, **because it can be deducted from the selected subnet**

Now, the million dollar question, how do I get the Availability Zone from the Subnet in CloudFormation?  As far as I can tell, I can't do a GetAtt for AZ on my ENI.

Any solution welcome!

Comment: You could use a cross-stack reference, export the AZ using GetAtt and import the AZ for the subnet using `Fn::ImportValue` assuming the subnet itself exists in another cloudformation stack. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html

Comment: unfortunately the subnet does not exist in a separate AZ. It's just a user input in this case.

Comment: You could try using a custom lambda backed resource to get the AZ similar to what's described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html).

Comment: That would work indeed. Not fan of having to impose IAM role creation on my users... Ideally I can find a cloudformation only solution, but otherwise I'll revert to that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, ***you can't*** retrieve the Availability Zone from the Subnet.

**But if you have total control of the template or resources that supplies the parameter to your template there are workarounds**

If have control over the source the provides you the `Subnet` parameter, you can return also the `Availability Zone` from that source as an `Outputs` and supply it in your template as a parameter where you create ENI and EBS.

In addition, you could also create the Subnet in the same template you will create the ENI and EBS and use the `{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "mySubnet", "AvailabilityZone" ] }`

**Question**(sorry, my rep can't allow me to comment yet)

Do you happen to have dynamic values or resources to be created that depends on availability zones? If yes, you can create [Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) and if that is not enough, you could add [Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) in your template.

Comment: currently no control on these things... would be nice to get AWS to generate an AZ as the output of an ENI. It's not rocket science, they already provide this in their UI. Ugh...

Comment: Yep, there are still a couple of AWS console functionalities that cloudformation can't handle. They maybe offer or implement it in the future, but for now, we are at the mercy of what cloudformation can offer and work around it(lambda/hardcoded mappings/conditionals/bash scripts to some extent)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is something new, but according to the documentation you can get the AZ of a subnet with `GetAttr`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html#aws-resource-ec2-subnet-returnvalues

Quoting the documentation:

```
{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "mySubnet", "AvailabilityZone" ] }
```

**UPDATE:**

This suggestion is **wrong**, let me quote another documentation from AWS:

```
Supported Functions
For the Fn::GetAtt logical resource name, you cannot use functions. You must specify a string that is a resource's logical ID.

For the Fn::GetAtt attribute name, you can use the Ref function.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html#getatt-supported-functions

Comment: The problem is that the subnet is a parameter and already created so this might not work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629914/why-does-getattr-not-work-on-cloudformation-template-parameters

Comment: You are correct, we can't use "function" in resource name, only on attribute name.